# Selenium XPATH I have a list of checkboxes in a column. I am trying to select the checkbox in row 2

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of checkboxes in a column.  I am trying to select the checkbox from the 2nd row.  I have tried the following XPATH but it selects all of the checboxes.

```
//table[@id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_tb_match_rules"]//input[@type = "checkbox"]
```

The HTML is:

```
    <table id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_tb_match_rules" class="GOFU2OVJE border" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
<thead aria-hidden="false">
    <tr __gwt_header_row="0">
    <th class="GOFU2OVID GOFU2OVGD" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-311" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-310" colspan="1">
    <span style="">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </span>
    </th>
    <th class="GOFU2OVID GOFU2OVAE" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-313" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-312" colspan="1">Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<colgroup>
<tbody style="">
    <tr class="GOFU2OVCD GOFU2OVMD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <td class="GOFU2OVBD GOFU2OVDD GOFU2OVED GOFU2OVND">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-299" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVBD GOFU2OVDD GOFU2OVOD GOFU2OVLD GOFU2OVND">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-300" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input id="" class="" type="text" style="color: blue;" value=""/>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="GOFU2OVCE GOFU2OVJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    <td class="GOFU2OVBD GOFU2OVDE GOFU2OVED GOFU2OVKD">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-299" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GOFU2OVBD GOFU2OVDE GOFU2OVOD GOFU2OVKD">
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody style="display: none;">
<tfoot style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"/>
</table>
```

I would like to select the checkbox which has cell-gwt-uid-299
I cannot use UID-299 in the XPATH because this value is dynamic.  The number changes when you visit the page.

I have also tried the following XPATH using ancestor:

```
//table[@id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_tb_match_rules"]/ancestor::tr[1]//input[@type = "checkbox"]
```

and I have tried using preceding.  In Developer Tools window a checkbox is being highlighted but it is from a different table:

```
//table[@id="match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_tb_match_rules"]/preceding::tr[1]//input[@type = "checkbox"]
```

strange using preceding it is trying to select a checkbox from a different table.  Here is the HTML which was highlighted in develop tools when i use preceding:

```
    <table id="data_configuration_feeds_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="GOFU2OVFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
        <tr class="GOFU2OVEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
        <tr class="GOFU2OVFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
        <td class="GOFU2OVEG GOFU2OVGG GOFU2OVHG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-111" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
            </div>
        </td>
```

What XPATH could I use?

Comment: I would prefer css over xpath. Here's how - `(By.cssSelector(".GOFU2OVJE tbody tr input[type='checkbox']"))`

Comment: This one is selecting both checkboxes, in developer tools i select CSS and enter ".GOFU2OVJE tbody tr input[type='checkbox']"

Comment: Updated it - `(By.cssSelector(".GOFU2OVJE tbody tr input[type='checkbox']:nth-of-type(1)"))`

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffC I wasn't aware of jsbeautifier.org.  I will use that from now on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get the checkbox from the second row:

```
//table[@id='match_configuration_add_possible_tab_match_rules_tb_match_rules']//tbody/tr[2]//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Regarding the "preceding" and "ancestor":

This is because the checkbox you were searching is *AFTER*(within) your table-element. But using "preceding" as you did, you were searching for a checkbox *BEFORE* your table element (in the HTML code).
Similar for "ancestor". You were searching for an element "ABOVE" your table element that is a tr. Unless your table is part of another table, this will result in no fitting element. Instead you could have used "descendant", which will search "WITHIN" your element.

Comment: This works and thanks for the explanation of ancestor and preceding.